# Typeorm ignoring @column name of columns

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript, typeorm

I'm trying to delete some records from a entity, but typeorm is not using the @Column definition os the entity, thus performing a invalid sql:

```js
@Entity('table')
export class TableEntity implements Table {
  @Column({ name: 'user_id' })
  @PrimaryColumn()
  userId: number;
   ...
}
```

```js
this.repository.delete({
   userId: 1
})
```

```sql
DELETE FROM "table" WHERE "userId" = $1
```

and not

```sql
DELETE FROM "table" where "user_id" = $1
```

as I expected. Why?

Comment: [Same issue here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7620). Are you using MongoDB driver ?

Comment: Nope. I was using Postgresql driver. But it seams that the problem is with @PrimaryColumn. I had to switch the identity to an single id column, and I don't have this problem anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is probably long time solved by the author, but for those who ended up here from Google like me:

@PrimaryColumn() resets information previously provided by @Column().

So, instead of writing

```
@Column({ name: 'user_id' })
@PrimaryColumn()
userId: number;
```

one should write

```
@PrimaryColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
userId: number;
```

Have a great coding time guys!