# TypeORM createQueryBuilder where statement not respecting Enitity column name

Tags: typeorm

I have a pre-existing database table that has a column with a name of `account_number`, however, I wanted to reference this column in my code as `accountNumber` instead.

I have the following entity where I set the column name for the property type of `accountNumber` to be `account_number`

```
import { ObjectType, Field } from 'type-graphql';
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, BaseEntity } from 'typeorm';

@ObjectType()
@Entity({ database: 'main', name: 'account' })
class Account extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => String)
  @Column({ name: 'account_number' })
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  accountNumber!: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Column()
  organisation!: string;
}

export default Account;
```

This is the query builder that I am having an issue with

```
await AccountRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('a')
  .where('a.`account_number` = :accountNumber', { accountNumber: "abc123" })
  .getOne();
```

#### Expected Behavior

Query to resolve using the `account_number` column as is stated in the `Column` decorator.

```
SELECT `a`.`account_number` AS `a_accountNumber`, 
`a`.`organisation` AS `a_organisation` 
FROM `main`.`account` `a` 
WHERE a.`account_number` = 'abc123'
```

#### Actual Behavior

However, it seems to want to use `accountNumber` instead of `account_number` even though I have set it as so in the Entity

```
SELECT `a`.`accountNumber` AS `a_accountNumber`, 
`a`.`organisation` AS `a_organisation` 
FROM `main`.`account` `a` 
WHERE a.`account_number` = 'abc123'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing the same thing as in this question:

[Typeorm ignoring @column name of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911693/typeorm-ignoring-column-name-of-columns)

I'm not clear if this is documented, but I think something is wrong with explicitly named `PrimaryColumn()` and `PrimaryGeneratedColumn()`. If you absolutely need the generated column, you should be able to use

```
@Column(name: 'account_number',
        // "serial" type is equivalent to AI in PG
        type: 'serial',
        primary: true)
accountNumber: string;
```

(from here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1517).

Also, you don't need the `!` on a primary key, it's always going to be required.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. I am using a `mysql` db, so `serial` isn't a recognised value, but it still works without the `type` being defined.